# Copy columns from multiple text files in Python

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I have a large number of text files containg data arranged into a fixed number of rows and columns, the columns being separated by spaces. (like a .csv but using spaces as the delimiter). I want to extract a given column from each of these files, and write it into a new text file.

So far I have tried:

```
results_combined = open('ResultsCombined.txt', 'wb')

def combine_results():
    for num in range(2,10):  
        f = open("result_0."+str(num)+"_.txt", 'rb') # all the text files have similar filename styles
        lines = f.readlines()   # read in the data
        no_lines = len(lines)   # get the number of lines

             for i in range (0,no_lines):
                 column = lines[i].strip().split(" ")

                 results_combined.write(column[5] + " " + '\r\n')

             f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    combine_results()
```

This produces a text file containing the data I want from the separate files, but as a single column. (i.e. I've managed to 'stack' the columns on top of each other, rather than have them all side by side as separate columns). I feel I've missed something obvious.

In another attempt, I manage to write all the separate files to a single file, but without picking out the columns that I want.

```
import glob

files = [open(f) for f in glob.glob("result_*.txt")]  
fout = open ("ResultsCombined.txt", 'wb')

    for row in range(0,488):
      for f in files:
          fout.write( f.readline().strip() )
          fout.write(' ')
      fout.write('\n')

 fout.close()
```

What I basically want is to copy column 5 from each file (it is always the same column) and write them all to a single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the maximum number of rows in the files and if the files can fit into memory, then the following solution would work:

```
import glob

files = [open(f) for f in glob.glob("*.txt")]

# Given file, Read the 6th column in each line
def readcol5(f):
    return [line.split(' ')[5] for line in f]

filecols = [ readcol5(f) for f in files ]
maxrows = len(max(filecols, key=len))

# Given array, make sure it has maxrows number of elements.
def extendmin(arr):
    diff = maxrows - len(arr)
    arr.extend([''] * diff)
    return arr

filecols = map(extendmin, filecols)

lines = zip(*filecols)
lines = map(lambda x: ','.join(x), lines)
lines = '\n'.join(lines)

fout = open('output.csv', 'wb')
fout.write(lines)
fout.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I really like this solution - the number of files and rows can vary depending on what variables I've used in a simulation I'm running, so this saves me having to check what the highest row number is each time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not read all the entries from each 5th column into a list and after reading in all the files, write them all to the output file?

```
data = [
    [], # entries from first file
    [], # entries from second file
    ...
]

for i in range(number_of_rows):
    outputline = []
    for vals in data:
        outputline.append(vals[i])
    outfile.write(" ".join(outputline))
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this has pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Or this option (following your second approach):

```
import glob

files = [open(f) for f in glob.glob("result_*.txt")]  
fout = open ("ResultsCombined.txt", 'w')

for row in range(0,488):
   for f in files:
       fout.write(f.readline().strip().split(' ')[5])
       fout.write(' ')
   fout.write('\n')

fout.close()
```

... which uses a fixed number of rows per file but will work for very large numbers of rows because it is not storing the intermediate values in memory. For moderate numbers of rows, I'd expect the first answer's solution to run more quickly.

Comment: Thanks, I like the compactness of this method, and I may have to deal with very large numbers of rows at some point.